# Is Edmund Whittaker claim that Hilbert proved General Relativity days before Einstein valid?

Tags: relativity-theory, einstein, hilbert

Are the claims of Sir Edmund Whittaker regarding David Hilbert's derivation of the general relativity theory predated that of Einstein by five days?

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity_priority_dispute#cite_note-Whi53-1) Wikipedia article that I found contains the following statement:

> It was noted by Sir Edmund Whittaker in his 1954 book that David Hilbert had derived the theory of general relativity from an elegant variational principle almost simultaneously with Einstein's discovery of the theory.[B1] Hilbert's derivation of the theory predated that of Einstein by five days.[B2]

[B1] Whittaker, E. T (1953) A History of the Theories of Aether and Electricity: Vol 2 The Modern Theories 1900-1926. Chapter II: The Relativity Theory of Poincaré and Lorentz, Nelson, London.

[B2] Kip Thorne (1994): Black Holes and Time Warps: Einstein's Outrageous Legacy, W. W. Norton & Company; Reprint edition (January 1995). ISBN 0-393-31276-3

I am not sure if Whittaker's claim is valid or not.

Comment: Did you read the rest of the article? It says there that since the discovery of proofs of Hilbert's paper in 1997 Whittaker's "'commonly accepted view' has been challenged" and "it is not known whether Hilbert had formulated the field equations in an explicit form before 6 December (the date of the printer's proofs) or not". Even assuming that Hilbert derived the field equations on his own they were derived in the framework established by Einstein. And there are ample references to various interpretations and speculations on the subject. What exactly would you like us to add to all that here?